# How to reduce my ipa build size?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I have exported IPA build from Xcode 9.1 and my file size is 168 MB.
I have enabled and disabled bit code feature from build options in Xcode 9.1, But there is no change in IPA build file size it remains same as 168 MB. I am weird about this.

I will appreciate if anyone can help with this.
I really don't understand the concept of App Thinning.

Comment: If you're really concerned about this, why don't you look and _see_ what is taking up the space? An _.ipa_ file just a zipped package. Unzip it and look in the package!

Answer (score 2):

I guess code size is your smallest problem, therefor you don't see much of a change. If you want to have a smaller .ipa, you need to reduce your media files.

"App thinning" is something that happens on Apple site: Simply speaking, if a user downloads your app on a say iPhone, apple kicks out all stuff that does not match to your device, e.g. images for different resolutions than your phone. Therefore, your .ipa still contains all the data, but just the download for the end user is smaller.